# How to Run the C++ application continously?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to run my exe continously atleast for 24hours. How to accomplish this task, can someone  guide me on this..
My sample code is like this.. This Run_Continously() function has to execute continously in loop.

My previous attempts are like this:
First Attempt:

```
int Cmfc2Dlg::Run_Continously()
{
//Task 1: code to Take ScreenShot(img.tiff format)
//Task 2: code to Read the image file using OCR
//Task 3: Based on data read from the image, other operations are there.

return 1;
}

void Cmfc2Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonOK()
{
   while(Run_Continously());
}
```

This runs continuously. But the problem is CPU usage. AFter certain hours, for eg: after running 2hours, the application consumes 250,453 memory usage & finally application wont take any screenshot. Here i guess memory leak happens so..

Second Attempt:
In order to reduce the CPU usage, am making use of Thread concept & my code look like this:

```
//Header.h
class Cmfc2Dlg
{
 public:
    static DWORD WINAPI Run_Continously(LPVOID lpParam);
};

//source.cpp
DWORD WINAPI Cmfc2Dlg::Run_Continously(LPVOID lpParam)
{
 //Task 1: code to Take ScreenShot(img.tiff format)
//Task 2: code to Read the image file using OCR
//Task 3: Based on data read from the image, other operations are there.

return 0;
}

void Cmfc2Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonOK()
{
 Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,Run_Continously, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);  
    if ( Handle_Of_Thread_1 == NULL)
        ExitProcess(Data_Of_Thread_1);

    WaitForSingleObject(Handle_Of_Thread_1,INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(Handle_Of_Thread_1);

             Sleep(1000);  //This is mainly for so that CPU can can release some                  
              threads & everytime CPU is not busy.
 }
```

This code can run continously for  7 to 8 hours with memory usage 1.5k. After 8hours, again code wont take screenshot. Here memory usage is constant & am not getting why it is not working..??

My Third attempt:

```
void Cmfc2Dlg::Run_Continously()
{
//Task 1: code to Take ScreenShot(img.tiff format)
//Task 2: code to Read the image file using OCR
//Task 3: Based on data read from the image, other operations are there.


}

void Cmfc2Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonOK()
{
   while(1)
   {
      Run_Continously()

      Sleep(1000); //This is mainly for so that CPU can can release some                  
              threads & everytime CPU is not busy.
    }

}
```

This is also same as Second attempt.. This code can run upto 6 to 8 hours with 1.5k memory usage. After that no screenshots.

But one thing i know that, there are some exe's that can run for years together continously. Then why i cant do like that ??

If anyone knows this.. Please suggest me.. Any help/guidence would be  accepted..
Thank you.

My Screenshot code looks like this:

```
    DWORD WINAPI Cmfc2Dlg::ScreenShot()
    {
    CImage image;
CWnd *   pWnd;
CRect  rect;
BOOL   bStat;

HDC ScreenDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ScreenDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(ScreenDC, 100, 100);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);

//(H,W)500,500
//(x,y)78,242

bStat  =  image.Create(110, 64, 24);
ASSERT(bStat);
if ( ! bStat)
return  FALSE;

CImageDC imageDC(image);

::BitBlt(imageDC,  0 ,  0, 110, 64, ScreenDC,  25 ,  208, SRCCOPY);

CString strFull  =  "E:\\Thread\\Test.tiff";
HRESULT hr  =  image.Save(strFull, ImageFormatTIFF);

SelectObject(hDC, hOldBitmap);
DeleteDC(hDC);
::ReleaseDC(NULL, ScreenDC);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
TRACE( " Couldn't Save File: %s, %x " , (LPCTSTR)strFull, hr);
return  FALSE;
}
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to directly do anything special to let your program run continuously.

Comment: perhaps you should be looking at the snapshot code and whatever was causing your memory leak. Running something for ever is trivial enough, and you appear to have achieved that anyway

Comment: Well, you're the Guru, you should know that. Sorry, no offence, I just couldn't resist that :)

Comment: "But the problem is CPU usage. After certain hours [...] the application consumes 250,453 memory usage & finally application wont take any screenshot. Here i guess memory leak happens so..
[...] In order to reduce the CPU usage, am making use of Thread concept" This utterly makes no sense. The problem is CPU usage *because* you think memory is leaking and your *solution* is using multithreaded code?

Comment: Hi CAFxX.. Thanks for helping.. In my First attempt, I was Continously running the loop & memory usage goes on increasing and resulting the application crash.. But in Second attempt: After executing the thread, i will be terminating the thread. Here memory usage is constant.  If Screenshot code can run upto 8hours fine, then why it cant run after that ? Am quite confused with this..

Answer (score 0):

**Too much code is missing from the one you posted to tell what's wrong.**

If you're unable to fix it, just keep a simple loop alive with the button/GUI/whatever that, when the time comes, spawns a new process that performs operations 1), 2) and 3) and then terminates. If you don't need a fancy GUI, you can even just write a batch file that waits for a keystroke before spawning the process.

This way the OS will take care of freeing the resources in your stead.

Comment: Downvoting with no explanation is lame. Please care to explain why.

Comment: You're right, this is a legitimate answer.  For that, you should be at least at 0.  Upvoting to compensate.

Comment: For the record, [casting a vote to compensate for existing votes is not in the spirit of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74667/158958). Not saying you should revoke your vote, just making it clear how votes should work.

Comment: For all that matters, also [unwarrented, unmotivated downvotes are not in the spirit of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19268/how-should-down-voting-be-used?rq=1). Just my two cents.

Comment: sorry.. I dint understood.. Was my question worthless ??

Comment: There is no such thing as a worthless question, only ill-posed ones. You should always try to post a reduced *but* complete testcase (simplifying, the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem you're describing and that can be compiled/executed right away by somebody else). As a concrete example let's take your "third attempt": if I compile it, will it reproduce the problem? I doubt it will even compile (e.g. because of unresolved dependencies), let alone reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run your app continuously for 24 hours. Do you plan on doing anything in the meantime? How will you gracefully exit if you're in the middle operations?

Assuming your app is not worthless, and you actually have work to do during those 24 hours, you have a lot of options:

1. `CreateWaitableTimer`, another timer which this time uses a waitable object handle to signal completion. If you're already using waitable objects this will slip right into your design.
2. Use the lighter-weight `SetTimer` which does the same thing, with slightly less precision, using windows messages. If you use windows messages, this is probably a good choice.
3. Use `timeSetEvent` which will signal your app asynchronously after a certain time has elapsed. You could use this as a "it's time to exit" alarm. Use this to be signaled completely separately from your main worker.
4. Just check the system time occasionally. I would **not** recommend this because of system clock changes, daylight savings, automatic time adjustments. You could work around this using `GetTickCount` or similar, but most likely this is inferior to the other options. It does however let you adjust your logic on-the-fly (for example, `if(x) { shorten the time we should run by 5 minutes }`.

Between these three methods you have everything you need to be signaled when 24 hours is up. None of these methods will consume CPU as long as your worker doesn't. They are all events sent by the OS.

As for memory usage... you have a simple memory leak. Fix it in the usual ways. Figure out where the leak is and patch it. Without knowing more about your project that's all I can say. If you use `new` anywhere in your code, consider switching to a smart pointer.

Comment: Hi tenfour Thanks for guidence.. Yes in meantime am having middle operations. To exit the application gracefully,I will be using alarm. But am not getting why it is not running continously ??